# Wordpress Plugin Development - How to show custom widget in my backend dashboard from a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am building a custom wordpress plugin and from inside my plugin I would like to edit the backend wordpress dashboard widget welcome page. I would like to add a custom widget in the dashboard that will show details about my custom widget. I am registering the widget and the only this I can see is the title. The metaboxes or the html of the widget does not show in the dashboard only the title of the widget. Need help to show and the html that I add in my callback function. Anyone can help?

PS - I can do it working from my functions.php file but is there a way to make it work from a custom wordpress plugin?

Here is the code of my plugin.

```
function my_custom_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget("custom_help_widget", "WordPress Tutorials", "custom_dashboard_help");
}
add_action("wp_dashboard_setup", "my_custom_dashboard_widgets");

function custom_dashboard_help() {
    echo "<p>Welcome to your custom dashboard widget! Need help?></p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How plugin index.php page will like -

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Custom Dashboard Widget
  Description: Something
  Author: anonymous
  Version: 1.0.0
  Author URI: https://example.com/
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class Custom_Dashboard_Widgets {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }
    
    public function init(){
        add_action( "wp_dashboard_setup", array( $this, "my_custom_dashboard_widgets" ) );
    }
    
    public function my_custom_dashboard_widgets() {
        wp_add_dashboard_widget( "custom_help_widget", "WordPress Tutorials", array( $this, "custom_dashboard_help" ) );
    }
    
    public function custom_dashboard_help() {
        include_once("templates/dashboard.php");
        // or show all inside
        // echo "Welcome to your custom dashboard widget! Need help?";
    }
}

$custom_dashboard_widgets = new Custom_Dashboard_Widgets();
```

How templates > dashboard.php files will like -

```
<?php
echo "Welcome to your custom dashboard widget! Need help?";
?>

<h1> This is dashboard </h1>
```

[image]

Plugin Directory be like -

```
|--templates
|-----dashboard.php
|--index.php
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I would like to do everything within my plugin and not to edit any other templates.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I make the templates directory for splitting the files purpose, not to use the themes template. Your plugin directory will be like - `index.php , templates / dashboard.php` . It's ok if you want to add coding in one file there will be no problem.

Comment: I have tried it but nothing. It is still the same as before

Comment: I updated the answer, is it what you want to show? It's working flawlessly on my side.

Comment: I am copying and pasting your code but I still get the title only. I am using it inside a class inside a __constract function and I call it like this     add_action("wp_dashboard_setup", array($this, "my_custom_dashboard_widgets")); . That the only difference from your code and for some reason does not read the dashboard.php file

Comment: I updated to the OOP approach and it work fine. If not working on your side, you need to check on other plugins conflict or not.